# Use structural's directive template in child

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives

I wanted a way for a parent component to own a template to pass to a child component (`ReceiverComponent` in this case), that should display it in `ngFor`

```ts
@Directive({ selector: '[appSelector]' })
export class SelectorDirective<T> {
    constructor(
        public template: TemplateRef<T>
    ) {
        console.log(this.template);
    }
}
```

```html
<app-receiver>
  <div *appSelector="let item">Directive-template: {{item}}</div>
</app-receiver>
```

```ts
@Component({
    selector: 'app-receiver',
    templateUrl: './reciver.component.html', // Bellow
})
export class ReceiverComponent implements AfterContentInit {
    @ContentChild(SelectorDirective, { static: false }) item!: SelectorDirective<string>;

    items = Array.from({length: 10}).map((_, i) => `Item #${i}`);

    ngAfterContentInit() {
        console.log(this.item); // It is instance of the SelectorDirective
    }

}
```

```html
<ng-template let-item #template>
    <div>inline-template: {{item}}</div>
</ng-template>

<div *ngFor="let item of items">
  <ng-container
    [ngTemplateOutlet]="template"
    [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{$implicit: item, odd: odd}"
  ></ng-container>
  <ng-container
    [ngTemplateOutlet]="item.template"
    [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{$implicit: item, odd: odd}"
  ></ng-container>
</div>
```

I have created a minimal app, to debug this problem here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-whrjhr

---

Also, is there a way to pass the template to the `ngFor` directly so that I don't have to specify all the items that should go into context?

```
<ng-container
  [ngForOf]="items"
  [ngForTemplate]="template"
></ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ngFor` was setting variable `item`, thus `item.template` was undefined...

```
<div *ngFor="let value of items">
  <ng-container
    [ngTemplateOutlet]="template"
    [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{$implicit: value, odd: odd}"
  ></ng-container>
  <ng-container
    [ngTemplateOutlet]="item.template"
    [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{$implicit: value, odd: odd}"
  ></ng-container>
</div>
```